# нужно реализовать адаптив через javascript, а у меня получается только после обновления страницы

Tags: javascript

```
let block = 100

if(window.innerWidth <= 767){
  block = 100
} else{
  block = 75
}
```

Comment: Повесьте событие на изменение размера страницы.

Comment: window.addEventListener('resize' ,function(){})  такое не срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете функцию, допустим:

```
function calcBlock() {
  const widthWindow = window.innerWidth
  const block = widthWindow <= 767 ? 100 : 75
  console.log('Текущее значение window.innerWidth=', widthWindow, ' block=', block)
  return block
}
```

Добавляете ее в обработчик, используя [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', calcBlock)
```

Пример (изменяйте размеры окна браузера, чтобы видеть как происходит срабатывание обработчика на событие `resize`)

```js
function calcBlock() {
  const widthWindow = window.innerWidth
  const block = widthWindow <= 767 ? 100 : 75
  console.log('Текущее значение window.innerWidth=', widthWindow, ' block=', block)
  return block
}


window.addEventListener('resize', calcBlock)
calcBlock()
console.log('Изменяйте размеры окна, чтобы увидеть событие resize в действии')
```